# How to change elements(img's) position via radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got an image positioned in container and 3 radio buttons. I would like to add another images appear over the container main image when some of the radio buttons is chosen. Each of the buttons will have different positions of the images shown when they are active.

So far I got that:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" id="q156" name="quality[25]" value="1" /> 1
    </label> 
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" id="q157" name="quality[25]" value="2" /> 2
    </label> 
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" id="q158" name="quality[25]" value="3" /> 3
    </label> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-fl">
    <div id="img_box">
        <img style="width: 100%;" src="img/other/rounded_corners.png" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Not possible with CSS with the current structure. You cannot affect the css of an element based on the child of a previous element.

Comment: could you give me some example with other structure?

Comment: If you could put a demo tigether in Jsfiddle.net we might be able to offer alternatives...but generally JS is probably your best option.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=fmlkIeuT72

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the image sources as data attr. to the radio button.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" id="q156" name="quality[25]" value="1" data-img="http://placehold.it/350x150/ff0000" /> 1
    </label> 
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" id="q157" name="quality[25]" value="2" data-img="http://placehold.it/350x150/00ff00"/> 2
    </label> 
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" id="q158" name="quality[25]" value="3" data-img="http://placehold.it/350x150/0000ff" /> 3
    </label> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-fl">
<div id="img_box"></div>
```

The img box is empty but size and image are set by css:

```
#img_box{
    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/350x150/ff0000')
}
```

Then add a event that append a img overlay on click (using source from radio buttons):

```
 $(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
        $this = $(this)
        $img_box = $('#img_box')
        $overlay = $('<img/>').attr('src',$this.data('img'))
        $img_box.html('').append($overlay)                    
    });
})
```

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/fmytsjv7/1/

Comment: I would like to keep the main image and show the other images when some of the buttons is active over the main.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks alot m8!

Comment: It's working perfect in the jsfiddle but when I tryed to use it in my page it's not working, like there is no JS you have any idea why? Buttons are switching but image does not apear over the main one.....

Comment: nope the problem was that the buttons wich I used didn't actualy worked.
because I changed the radio button to look like normal button, after I changed that it worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using jQuery, and binding event handler to your radio buttons.

Like this one:

```
$('input:radio[name="quality[25]"]').change(function(){ });
```

Then add the handler to alter the attributes/css properties of the target image container or the image element directly.

You can use jQuery `.css()` to alter css properties of your target element

Like:

```
$("#img_box").css({"height":"100px","width":"100px",background:"red"});
```

While, you can use jQuery `.attr()` to alter the attributes of your target element.

Like: (in this case its the img's "src" attribute)

```
$("#img_box > img").attr("src","path/to/whatever/image");
```

**[HERE'S A SAMPLE IN JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/o0j7vnc8/)**

I see that you included jQuery tag in your question, so I assume you are interested in jQuery based solution.

Comment: You have to replace the srcs with valid image urls.